# MATCH AGAINST fails to find results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to develop a search engine in PHP + MySQLi using MATCH...AGAINST but I've found something really strange: if I run the next instruction, then no results are returned

```
SELECT * FROM `conditions` WHERE MATCH(`desc`) AGAINST ('*zero*')
```

but there is actually one row in the table with desc="zero code"

The strange thing here is that if I replace the string "zero code" with "zerx code" and I search against "zerx" instead of "zero", then the result is returned.

Could anybody give me a clue on what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'*zero*'` or only `'zero'` ?

Comment: I've tried all possible combination 'zero', 'zero*', '*zero', '*zero*' and does not make any difference

Comment: Is 'zero' any kind of keyword?

Comment: but I assume it is a string. In case it is considered a keyword, how should I escape it?

Comment: if we use `quot` or `double quot` it should not considered as keyword. [as this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) .Thinking whats going wrong in your code/statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170769/discussion-between-ramlal-s-and-carles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different word :)

MySQL has a [list of words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) which it doesn't index, and 'zero' is in that list.

Comment: Oh great.... So, is there any way to force that or escape that word or something? I really need to search that word, in fact is important, but I would like to avoid using LIKE '%%'. By the way: thank you very much!

Comment: You can change the list by following the instructions in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). After that you will need to rebuild the index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `conditions` WHERE MATCH(`desc`) AGAINST ('+zero')
```

[refer here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)